# Java Regex for picking operands off an expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a situation where in i have to pick variable from an expression string as shown  below.

```
name = 'Bruce Wayne' ||TrackId = 12 || age =9 &&sample = 7 || thisistoolong = 'asda'
```

I tried the pattern

```
"(([\\d\\s\\S&&[^\\&\\|]]+)=([\\d\\s\\S&&[^\\&\\|]]+))"
```

but it does not seem to scan the entire string.

How can i improve my pattern so that it can pick 'name' , 'TrackId', 'age', 'sample' and 'thisistoolong' ( as groups) from the string above.

I am aware that i could use String.split() and/or maybe recurse a smaller pattern but I figured it would be better for the performance if i could just use a regex to do the work instead. ( and also a cleaner code)

EDIT: thisistoolong could be a regular variable name in Javascript containing a Javascript valid value. Thanks to Andreas for pointing out the edge case where in the variable values can contain '||' and '&&' . Referring to Bohemian's answer, i got the idea of using Pattern.split() instead so that i can use a precompiled regex.

Comment: Much easier to use `yourString.split("||")` and recuse a smaller pattern.

Comment: What about [`\w+\s*=\s*([\w']+)`](https://regex101.com/r/lP9rL1/1) ?

Comment: ifly6 - I agree with the easy part but i am staying away from recursion for now. I might fall back to that if this doesn't help.

Comment: Jan - Nope. That doesn't work either. Please note that i am using java regex which is Perl based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get hung up on "performance" - various solutions using split (which uses regex) and Pattern Matchers will all have about the same performance, which will be good (under 0.1 ms typically).

Here's a one-liner:

```
String[] names = str.split(" =.*?($|\\s*(&&|\\|\\|)\\s*(?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$))");
```

See [ideone](https://ideone.com/suIemj) demo.

All that extra stuff in the regex allows both names and values to contain `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Good now. Well, except if string literals contain `&&` or `||`, of course. Regex is not a parser, so I'll quote [Jamie Zawinski](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski): *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*

Comment: @andreas is it honestly a possibility that names will contain `||` or `&&`? Really??? And would it be OK to disallow this? What about spaces - can they contain spaces? At some point it's reasonable to disallow certain input; the users of the API will accept reasonable restrictions.

Comment: @Andreas nevertheless, I have edited the answer to allow `&&` and `||` in names.

Comment: I agree that `name` will likely not contain `||` or `&&`, but I can't say what kind of text will be in `thisistoolong`, can you? The entire input that is being analyzed is dynamic, so you don't have any idea what it is, except that it is an *expression* that allows text literals. As such, you need a parser, not a regex, to analyze it.

Comment: Try this input and regex will fail: `name = 'Bruce || Wayne' || TrackId = 12||age =9 && sample = 7 || thisistoolong = 'asda'`. You can try to complicate regex with lookarounds to handle that, but what if text literal contains a `'`. Well, it's currently undefined by OP, but what if is uses C-style escapes with ``\``? Now you have to count `'` *and* ``\\`` in obscure combinations. Better just realize that regex is a poor choice for parsing expressions and get a real expression parser involved.

Comment: @andreas there's a regex solution even for that. See edited answer, which allows `&&` and `||` in both names and values. I'm stopping now btw. This solution is more than adequate IMHO.

Comment: This doesn't work in Java ( where regex is Perl based). I do see it working in your demo link for Ruby based regex. Ideone - https://ideone.com/cvwvYc

Comment: @nishm wow. I didn't believe it until I tried it, but you're right. I managed to get it working by slightly altering the regex - see answer and [ideone demo](https://ideone.com/noMj2U). Thanks for pointing this out. I actually don't yet understand why the original answer didn't work, but I will set aside done time to analyse it.

Comment: @Bohemian This works but only if there are spaces around '||' '&&' . This is my fault since i did not put the string in question without spaces around them. I have updated the question. Also note that the variable names wouldn't contain '&&' or '||' so thats one less thing to worry about. So no more whacky||crazy&&name but i do like your extensive test. Updated ideone - https://ideone.com/daUetr

Comment: @NishM changed to optional whitespace around delimiters, added ideone link

Comment: @NishM that was a marathon... I'm moving to Seattle soon; maybe I'll collect on those beers one day :)